# Myserious 100mb parition on HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, ssd

I just installed Windows 10 on a newly formatted SSD. I also have two HDD's in this machine. After installing Windows 10 a 100mb partition appeared in Disk 0, this isn't the SSD, but a 2TB HDD and it is not where windows is installed. I'm almost positive this partition did not exists before I reinstalled windows. It does have a drive letter assigned and when I go to explore it the drive is totally empty. So what's up with this? Can I get rid of it?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[I'd suggest not to touch that](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/10408-whats-100mb-partition-can-i-delete.html).

If I'm correct it's a system partition that contains files important to the boot process.